# setting split array to empty in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following file

```
Hello. this is an example
    Car=toyota Fruit=Orange Name=John
    01
    Car=toyota Fruit=Orange Name=John
    02
    Car=toyota Fruit=Orange Name=John
    03
End of the file
```

I run this awk code in shell

```
awk -F "\t" '{n=split($2,a); for(i=1 ; i<=n ; i++) {if(a[i] ~ "^Fruit*") a[i]=""} print}' myFile.txt
```

So the field separator is a `tab`. Then I split the Second field using `space`. If any of my subfields (which are separated by space) starts with `Fruit` I want to delete it.

This doesn't work. It does not delete it.

---

Expected output

```
Hello. this is an example
    Car=toyota Name=John
    01
    Car=toyota Name=John
    02
    Car=toyota Name=John
    03
End of the file
```

Please no use of extra packages. I want it as default as possible. (using awk,sed,grep would be great)

Comment: Show your expected output, there might be better ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If any of my subfields (which are separated by space) starts with
>   `Fruit` I want to delete it.

You can use `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/Fruit=[^ ]* //g' inputfile
Hello. this is an example
    Car=toyota Name=John
    01
    Car=toyota Name=John
    02
    Car=toyota Name=John
    03
End of the file
```

Comment: @devnull This Works GREAT. but why doesn't it work for Name??? I try `sed 's/Name=[^ ]* //g' inputfile` and the names dont get deleted?

Comment: @Matin If `Name` is the last field in the file, you'd need to say: `sed 's/Name=.*//g' inputfile`.

Comment: @Matin The reason that it doesn't work for `Name` is that by saying `/Name=[^ ]* /` (note the space after `*`), you're trying to match a space as well, which probably doesn't exist since it's the last field.

Comment: But that's the thing. Maybe I want to delete the last field maybe one of the middles. I don't know this when I write the script. Isn't there 1 notation for it?

Comment: I FOUND IT.  This works whether it's last field or not `sed 's/Name=[^ ]*//g' inputfile` Correct?

Comment: @Matin, make the space optional: `/Name=[^ ]* ?/`, should always work

Comment: @Matin: Use **`sed 's/Name=[^ ]* *//g'`**

Comment: @devnull Thank you. Rated.. But which one's better. This `sed 's/Name=[^ ]*//g'` or this `sed 's/Name=[^ ]* *//g'`

Comment: @Matin Use the second one; the one suggested by anubhava.  It wouldn't leave an extra space in case you're deleting a field from the middle of the line.

Comment: You should anchor the start of the keyword somehow and use `[^ ][^ ]* *` if you're OK with single space chars and BREs. Try the above with `ForeName=John Name=JohnSmith` in your input and removing `Name=`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk   '{gsub(/ Fruit[^ ]*/,"")}1' myFile.txt
```

Gives:

```
Hello. this is an example
    Car=toyota Name=John
    01
    Car=toyota Name=John
    02
    Car=toyota Name=John
    03
End of the file
```

Comment: Cannot use `gsub` :/ sorry

Comment: This will replace `Fruit` string from anywhere in the line, not just the 2nd field.

Comment: @anubhava, from the OP: `If any of my subfields (which are separated by space) starts with Fruit I want to delete it`

Comment: @perreal: Read a sentence before `Then I split the Second field using space`

Comment: @anubhava, OP means the second field after tab splitting

Comment: @perreal That's right. I meant the second field after tab splitting

Comment: @perreal because the servers I use don't supported nor do I have the permission to install

Comment: @Matin - if your awk does not support gsub() then you are using old, broken awk which will make your life miserable trying to work around it's lacks and idiosyncrasies and fail cryptically in various scenarios. Are you on Solaris where the default awk in /usr/bin/awk is old, broken awk? If so switch to nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk. Otherwise - you've GOT to get a modern awk before the one you're using completely wrecks your data.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file                                                          
Hello. this is an example
    Car=toyota ForeName=John Name=JohnSmith 
    01
End of the file

$ sed -r 's/(^|[[:space:]])ForeName=[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/\1/' file
Hello. this is an example
    Car=toyota Name=JohnSmith 
    01
End of the file

$ sed -r 's/(^|[[:space:]])Name=[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/\1/' file    
Hello. this is an example
    Car=toyota ForeName=John 
    01
End of the file
```